# Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all]

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a pine script code to plot some lines conditionally. I see pine script v5, plot() function has display argument, still I am getting an weird error. Any idea what it could be?

Code:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title="Gann Levels", shorttitle="GIL", overlay=false, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

from_previous_day_low = input.bool(title="Previous day low", defval=true)
from_previous_day_high = input.bool(title="Previous day high", defval=true)

[previous_day_high, previous_day_low] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [high[1], low[1]])

sqrt_previous_day_low = math.round(math.sqrt(previous_day_low))
sqrt_previous_day_high = math.round(math.sqrt(previous_day_high))

display_supports() => from_previous_day_low ? display.none : display.all

display_resistances() => from_previous_day_high ? display.none : display.all


s1 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_high - 0.250, 2))
s2 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_high - 0.500, 2))
s3 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_high - 0.750, 2))

r1 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_low - 0.250, 2))
r2 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_low - 0.500, 2))
r3 = math.round(math.pow(sqrt_previous_day_low - 0.750, 2))

plot(series=s1, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_supports())
plot(series=s2, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_supports())
plot(series=s3, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_supports())


plot(series=r1, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_resistances())
plot(series=r2, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_resistances())
plot(series=r3, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), display=display_resistances())
```

Errors:

```
line 26: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all];
line 27: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all];
line 28: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all];
line 31: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all];
line 32: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all];
line 33: Invalid argument 'display' in 'plot' call. Possible values: [display.none, display.all]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply your condition to the `series` argument of `plot()`. The `display` argument is whether to enable or disable the plot by default and I believe it must be a constant.

And you probably want to change the style to something like `plot.style_circles` so your line won't be connected.

```
plot(from_previous_day_low ? s1 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)
plot(from_previous_day_low ? s2 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)
plot(from_previous_day_low ? s3 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)


plot(from_previous_day_high ? r1 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)
plot(from_previous_day_high ? r2 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)
plot(from_previous_day_high ? r3 : na, linewidth=2, color=color.new(#16F6DE, 10), style=plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Strange API plot is then. The function returning the value it asks for, but it can't be a function or expression. May be later the language will be fix this. A good usecase to plot conditionally is missing from `display` args.

Comment: I agree that the error message should be more clear. I will report this to the dev team.